# Why c++ compiler is not giving any errors , c compiler is able to give error , when calling enum as a function

Tags: c++, c, gcc, enums, g++

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum{
    V1=1,
    V2
}myenum;

void fun(myenum val){
    printf("%d",val);
}

int main(){
    fun(myenum());//why no error 
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked with g++ and gcc compiler. C compiler is able to give error as follows:

Compilation failed due to following error(s).main.c: In function ‘main’:

main.c:22:6: error: expected expression before ‘myenum’

22 |  fun(myenum());//why no error

Comment: C has no `type(value)` syntax (the functional cast), and by extension no `type()`.